# Limit Worksheet Event Macro to Certain Columns

Tags: excel, vba

The following code will update cells to 1-5 based on doubleclicks on the cell.

I'm looking to limit this to a few columns in the spreadsheet (e.g. if I doubleclick on A2, nothing should happen).

Clearly the `.Columns("B:C")` is not in the right spot.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet.Columns("B:C")_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True

If Target.Value < 5 Then
    Target.Value = Target.Value + 1

Else
    Target.Value = 5

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you use an if block to test if the Target is in the range or not: `If Not Intersect(Range("B:C"),Target) is Nothing then`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Scott Craner in the comments, the proper way to handle this is to test if the Target range intersects the columns.

I would also recommend setting `Cancel = True`.  This prevents the cell from going into edit mode.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Columns("B:C"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value < 5 Then
            Target.Value = Target.Value + 1
        Else
            Target.Value = 5
        End If
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet Before Double-Click: Increment Cell Value

- Adjust the values in the event procedure.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Reference (set) the range (columns).
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = SetColumnsUR(Me, "B2:C2,E2,G2:H2")
    ' Check if the double-clicked cell ('Target') doesn't intersect.
    If Intersect(srg, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ' Write the integer according to the logic.
    Target.Value = MyIntegerLogic(Target.Value, 1, 5)
    ' Suppress the default behavior of double-clicking a cell.
    Cancel = True
End Sub

Function SetColumnsUR( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal FirstRowAddress As String) _
As Range
    With ws.Range(FirstRowAddress)
        With .Areas(1).Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
            Set SetColumnsUR = Intersect(.Cells, ws.UsedRange)
        End With
        If .Areas.Count = 1 Then Exit Function
        Set SetColumnsUR = Intersect(SetColumnsUR.EntireRow, .EntireColumn)
    End With
End Function

Function MyIntegerLogic( _
    ByVal Value As Variant, _
    ByVal MinInteger As Long, _
    ByVal MaxInteger As Long) _
As Long
    Dim Number As Long: Number = MinInteger - 1
    If VarType(Value) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
        If Int(Value) = Value Then ' is a whole number (integer)
            Select Case Value
                Case MinInteger To MaxInteger - 1: Number = Value + 1 ' 1.)
                Case MaxInteger: Number = MaxInteger ' 2.)
                Case Else ' covered below
            End Select
        End If
    End If
    If Number = MinInteger - 1 Then Number = MinInteger ' 3.) all other cases
    MyIntegerLogic = Number
End Function
```